# Where and how are JavaScript object properties stored in memory?

Tags: javascript, memory

I have recently started learning JavaScript and learned that one can add (and delete) properties on the fly, unlike in C#, for example, which forces one to define all the properties inside a class. Where and how, then, does JavaScript store each object's properties? Let's say I have an object as follows:

```
Line 1: let obj = {};
Line 2: obj.prop1 = 1;
```

In line 1, I can see an empty object created in the heap, but when an extra property is added in line 2, does JavaScript automatically re-create the same object at a different memory location to accommodate the new property, similar to the way, for example, C# would when an array or list exceeds the original size? Thank you!

Comment: That would be an implementation detail for the different environments that will run your code. Usually, the object is not recreated. JS objects act a lot like hashes. In C# [dynamic objects act a lot like JS objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709333/how-to-create-own-dynamic-type-or-dynamic-object-in-c) where you can change them at runtime.

Comment: For a language like JavaScript, such details should not be something you worry about for most of the code you'll write.

Comment: Javascript objects are generally implemented as hash tables at the C level. So they behave like how hash tables would in C. It is a bit more complicated though because of inheritance (prototype chain) but the gist of it is that it objects are hash tables. In fact for V8 (Google Chrome, Node.js etc.) you can see the hash table implementation as the storage of Object properties here: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/ordered-hash-table.cc

Comment: As for (2). No. It would not recreate the entire hash. It would just create an entry that points to the number `1`. Even Arrays in javascript don't re-create the entire array when you add a new item because javascript arrays are not implemented as arrays at the C level - they're linked lists (usually with additional indexing logic to make array access faster)

Comment: Thanks, @VLAZ! I didn't know C# has dynamic objects that act very similar to JS objects--pretty cool to know!

Comment: @Pointy True, but I sometimes like to go down rabbit holes in an effort to gain deeper understanding, which I believe ultimately helps me become a better coder. Having said that, I understand your point.

Comment: @slebetman I see--that makes more sense! With C# being my first programming language, I found JavaScript objects a bit strange, but your explanation does clear it up a bit. Thanks for adding additional information about JS arrays as well, which I didn't know about!