# Part of variable name has to be dynamic

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, dynamic-variables

I want `dynamicVariable` below to hold different name each time

```
 Price.dynamicVariable.Item1
```

Data.cs:

```
namespace ProjectName.Shared.Price
{
    public class Price
    {
        
            public static readonly Tuple<double?, double?> applePrice = new Tuple<double?, double?>(2, 10);

            public static readonly Tuple<double?, double?> bananaPrice = new Tuple<double?, double?>(1, 2);

           public static readonly Tuple<double?, double?> orangePrice = new Tuple<double?, double?>(2, 4);

    }

}
```

ItemComponent.cs:

```
using ProjectName.Shared.Price   

// I will be getting `ID` as "applePrice", "bananaPrice" or "orangePrice" dynamically
Id = dynamicVariable  
    
    // how to substitute ID below with dynamic ID's based on what we receive
    Min = Price.ID.Item1 
    Max = Price.ID.Item2
    
If Id passed was "bananaPrice", I expect ID to hold "bananaPrice".So, it will become
    
    Min = Price.bananaPrice.Item1 // so that value received would be 1 (from Data.cs)
    Max = Price.bananaPrice.Item2 // value received would be 2
```

May I know how I can achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: c# does have some support for dynamic objects. Read about the ExpandoObject class. But, I've found it is rarely better than using a Dictionary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709333/how-to-create-own-dynamic-type-or-dynamic-object-in-c

Comment: This is more of a design problem that you're trying to solve in a weird way. Why not have an interface, `IPricedItem`, then implement that interface on classes that represent your domain (i.e. fruits)? Then you could just maintain a collection of `IPricedItem`s. You're thinking about the problem domain backwards: A price doesn't have items, items have prices.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, V>` for this where `V` is your `Tuple<double?, double?>`. I'd advise against using a tuple, though.

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`, `ExpandoObject`, or reflection for this. Any of those options will take you down a dark path.

Comment: You can dynamically access variable names and such via reflection. C# has a pretty powerful support on this front and you can do almost anything. Although this is quite inefficient and I personally try to avoid it as much as possible, mainly in parts which are often accessed. The other option would be what some people here are suggesting: relying on another layer/dictionary to map variable names to variables. That's fine, but still unnecessarily inefficient if you ask my opinion. In this case, I would go with the simplest and most efficient option: conditions, switch statements or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do things like this is to make the code more abstract so you do not have to fiddle around with anything 'dynamic'. For example by using a dictionary and a enum:

```
public enum Fruit{banana, apple, orange}

public Dictionary<Fruit, (decimal? Min, decimal? Max)> Price = new (){...}

public double? GetMinPrice(Fruit fruit) => Price[fruit].Min;
```

If you need to convert a string to a fruit, see [enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-7.0). For more serious use cases you should consider using a database.

Comment: Thank you. Worked it out using the idea mentioned.